# Trying to show full size image from thumbnails retrieved using php and database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to use thumbnails retrieved from database. PHP is working fine and displaying my thumbnails. I don't know how to get the id from database into the `imageID` for JavaScript function and `getElementById`, to display as full size when clicked.   I can do straight JavaScript inline `onsubmit` in my code.  The inline JavaScript is working; the thumbnail is being displayed, and when clicked a full size shows, but I want to use my database retrieved images to show the full size image when clicked.  Do you think you can help me with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //function that shows full sized image of the thumbnail 
        function showImage(imageID) {
        //first hide all images
   document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'none';
   //then display the one that had its thumbnail clicked.
        document.getElementById(imageID).style.display = '';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1></h1>


<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "travel1";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) 
    die ("Unable to connect to database: " . $conn->connect_error );

$sql = "select * from what_to_do
    where DESTINATION='NEW YORK CITY'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >= 0) {
    echo "<table>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>".$row["THUMBNAIL"]."</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
}   
else {
        echo "You have no destinations";
}
$conn->close(); 
?>
<p>
<img id="image1" alt="" src="images/NewYork/Pick7/9-11show.jpg"
    style="display: none" />
</p>
<p>
<img alt="" src="="images/NewYork/Pick7/9-11thumb.JPG"style="width:100px;
 height:100px" onclick="showImage('image1')" />       
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code the second img tag is closed prematurely, like  src="something" etc etc. If that tag were properly formed, I think this should work?

Otherwise, you would just do something like " src="/blah" />

Hopefully that answers your question?

And then for the I onclick function just do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume a lot, but here goes!

The above answer is correct, you are prematurely closing an image tag at the bottom of your code, it should be like this:

```
<img alt="" src="images/NewYork/Pick7/9-11thumb.JPG" style="width:100px;
 height:100px;" onclick="showImage('image1')" />
```

But otherwise there are a few other issues to address...

First, by typing in the specific name of the destination for each query on every page you'll be defeating the purpose in using a database! Just like you've mentioned, you need to use the ID and pull in the data accordingly.

To do this you need to define what the ID is by letting the user select the destination on a previous page/section(in your example a destination list might be appropriate with all the destinations in some kind of order, be that ascending or descending ect... PHP has a few different ways.)

So first, the query to sort by ID is:

```
SELECT * FROM travel1 order by id desc
```

and then to set the ID in the URL when the destination link is clicked, here's an example link using php to carry the ID to the next page:

```
<a href="/destination-info.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">more info</a>
```

Once you get to the destination info page(that's what I'm calling your above code), filter your data so that you can access the specific destination by ID by firstly adding this to your page(after you've connected to the database that is):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '',$_GET['id']);
        $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM travel1 WHERE id='$id' ");
        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<td>".$row["THUMBNAIL"]."</td>"; 
         }

         } else { 
 echo "We're having some issues..."; 
}
?>
```

The above code will pick up the database ID from your URL which was carried over from the previous page(your new destination list) and can be echoed out like your other links such as:

```
'echo "<td>".$row["THUMBNAIL"]."</td>";'
```

I hope this helped! =D

Comment: Thank you both! I want to give a little more background before going this route.  I already have a destination page with radio buttons that takes us to this NEW YORK page; there are 3 others dest pages.  Each page is going to the database and picking up 6 thumbnail images.  From what I read it sounds  like the thumbnail page has to generate it's own new page?  Did I understand?  In-order to use the ID  from the database with the img, I need to create another page?  Is there a way I can get the ID into Javascript so that I can use it to present larger image when clicked  on the same page?

Comment: I am taking out the misleading javascript function along with the hardcoded img tags.  I really need to use the DB, not hardcode it.

Comment: Yeah you got it! Now once you've got a better grasp of how to do it you'll be able to utilize the above code as it seems that you're not fully educated on the power of PHP! Here's a really good resource to get started, I know it's a video and it's about making a shop but it's all relevant and it got me going with PHP! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65gV8JOgWkQ 

Also, in order to use your ID in a script just echo the ID as normal but wrap it in it's own php tags <?php echo $row['id']; ?>

-Also, only pay attention to the PHP as he is still using mysql to query the databse and not mysqli!

Comment: Thank you MEOWPLATES!  The video links were awesome!  Especially the ones on database.  So, I went and redid my database to be more focused.  The database no longer includes all the HTML, so that I can use it.  I empowered my PHP Interweaving javascript and php into it.  But you are so right, I'm just starting.  Can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: if ($result->num_rows >= 0) {
  echo "<table>";
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo '<img id="'.$row->["ID"].'"src="'.$row->     ["THUMBNAIL"].'"' onclick="showImage('imageID')" onclick="showCaption('captionID')"</>';
      }
      echo "</table>";

Comment: Good job! And no problem :) 
Presuming that you're hiding the image with CSS and displaying it with onClick, I think you'll need something similar to what I used above.

https://jsfiddle.net/yts31b4a/
Sorry it's in JSfiddle, can't find a PHP shareable sandbox.
Enjoy! :)